# issue with adding a new member in etcd cluster

Tags: etcd

I have 3 node etcd cluster running on docker

````
Node1:

etcd-advertise-client-urls: "http://sensu-backend1:2379"
etcd-initial-advertise-peer-urls: "http://sensu-backend3:2380"
etcd-initial-cluster: "sensu-backend1=http://sensu-backend1:2380,sensu-backend2=http://sensu-backend2:2380,sensu-backend3=http://sensu-backend3:2380"
etcd-initial-cluster-state: "new" # new or existing
etcd-listen-client-urls: "http://0.0.0.0:2379"
etcd-listen-peer-urls: "http://0.0.0.0:2380"
etcd-name: "sensu-backend1"

Node2:

etcd-advertise-client-urls: "http://sensu-backend2:2379"
etcd-initial-advertise-peer-urls: "http://sensu-backend3:2380"
etcd-initial-cluster: "sensu-backend1=http://sensu-backend1:2380,sensu-backend2=http://sensu-backend2:2380,sensu-backend3=http://sensu-backend3:2380"
etcd-initial-cluster-state: "new" # new or existing
etcd-listen-client-urls: "http://0.0.0.0:2379"
etcd-listen-peer-urls: "http://0.0.0.0:2380"
etcd-name: "sensu-backend2"```

Node3:

etcd-advertise-client-urls: "http://sensu-backend3:2379"
etcd-initial-advertise-peer-urls: "http://sensu-backend3:2380"
etcd-initial-cluster: "sensu-backend1=http://sensu-backend1:2380,sensu-backend2=http://sensu-backend2:2380,sensu-backend3=http://sensu-backend3:2380"
etcd-initial-cluster-state: "new" # new or existing
etcd-listen-client-urls: "http://0.0.0.0:2379"
etcd-listen-peer-urls: "http://0.0.0.0:2380"
etcd-name: "sensu-backend3"
````

I am running each node as a docker service without persisting the etcd data directory.
When I start all the nodes together etcd forms the cluster.

If I delete one node and try to add as **etcd-initial-cluster-state: "existing"** then I get following error
`{"component":"etcd","level":"fatal","msg":"tocommit(6264) is out of range [lastIndex(0)]. Was the raft log corrupted, truncated, or lost?","pkg":"raft","time":"2020-12-09T11:32:55Z"}`

After stopping etcd, I deleted the node from cluster using **etcdctl member remove**  . When I restart container with empty etcd data directory then I get cluster id mismatch error.

`{"component":"backend","error":"error starting etcd: error validating peerURLs {ClusterID:4bccd6f485bb66f5 Members:[\u0026{ID:2ea5b7e4c09185e2 RaftAttributes:{PeerURLs:[http://sensu-backend1:2380]} Attributes:{Name:sensu-backend1 ClientURLs:[http://sensu-backend1:2379]}} \u0026{ID:9e83e7f64749072d RaftAttributes:{PeerURLs:[http://sensu-backend2:2380]} Attributes:{Name:sensu-backend2 ClientURLs:[http://sensu-backend2:2379]}}] RemovedMemberIDs:[]}: member count is unequal"}`

Please help me on fixing the issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you delete a node that was in a cluster, you should manually delete it from etcd cluster also i.e. by doing 'etcdctl remove '.

And member mismatch count error is because 'etcd-initial-cluster' still has all 3 entries of nodes, you need to remove that entry of deleted node from this field also in all containers.

Comment: I solved it by manually adding the member